# How to convert following Json object as a string like below

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a json object as follows,

```
{
  "category": "music",
  "location": {
    "city": "Braga"
  },
  "date": {
    "start": {
      "$gte": "2017-05-01T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "end": {
      "$lt": "2017-05-12T18:30:00.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

i need to create a query string as follows,

```
category=music | location.city = Braga | date.start.$gte = 2017-05-01T18:30:00.000Z | date.end.$lt = 2017-05-12T18:30:00.000Z
```

How can I achieve this?

This is what i have tried.

```
 _.each(this.filter, (val: string, key: string) => {
      if (key && val) {
        filterArray.push(`${key}=${val}`);
      }
    });
```

Comment: That is not a querystring

Comment: ok just a string! @NitzanTomer how to convert?

Comment: Creating the query string (or whichever is the type of object that you want to get) assigning the values from the JSON object. Have you at least tried to code it?

Comment: yes i have tried like this  _.each(this.filter, (val: string, key: string) => {
      if (key && val) {
        filterArray.push(`${key}=${val}`);
      }
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the keys and build a path to the value. Later join pathes and add value and join to the final string.

```js
function getParts(object) {
    function iter(o, p) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
                iter(o[k], p.concat(k));
                return;
            }
            result.push(p.concat(k).join('.') + ' = ' + o[k]);
        });
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(object, []);
    return result.join(' | ');
}

var object = { "category": "music", "location": { "city": "Braga" }, "date": { "start": { "$gte": "2017-05-01T18:30:00.000Z" }, "end": { "$lt": "2017-05-12T18:30:00.000Z" } } },
    string = getParts(object);

console.log(string);
```

Comment: how can i convert this to support typescript

Comment: sorry, i can not help with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm late, but still.
Method `walk` recursively runs through your JSON and calls callback function with chain of `keys` and `value` as arguments.
Then `convert` uses `walk` to translate JSON into your format:

```
var walk = function( data, iterator, stack ) {
    var key;

    stack = stack || [];

    for ( key in data ) {
        if ( typeof data[ key ] === 'string' ) {
            iterator( stack.concat( [ key ] ), data[ key ] );
        } else {
            walk( data[ key ], iterator, stack.concat( [ key ] ) );
        }
    }
};

var convert = function( data ) {
    var result = [];

    walk( data, function( keys, value ) {
        result.push( keys.join( '.' ) + ' = ' + value );
    } );

    return result.join( ' | ' );
};

var query_string = convert( /* your JSON here */ );
```